# Transform property hides my svg image, after it exits my div

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to stretch a part of my svg image, using the transform property to scale only the middle part of my svg image using its id. It starts to scale, however when my image-middle-part exits the div, it doesn't display at all. I am trying to scale  my image-part from it's id instead of creating separate svg files for each part. I've tried searching everywhere and didn't find any solutions using jquery.

I tried using the transform property on the parent div and it works perfectly fine there. However when I try to do the same for the child (using the id to extend a specific part), it starts to strech but as soon as it leaves the parent div, it starts to disappear.

I want to strech my image such that the last part of my image is constant but the middle part only increases while pushing the last part of my image vertically as the middle part increases.

This is the image

[image: This is the pencil]

and it does something like this while using transform. I am trying to extend the red part only and..

[image]

Here the part is well extended, I checked using inspect but nothing shows at all after it leaves
the div.

And also shouldn't the bottom part be pushing downwards. What am I missing? If you can please provide me the reference if I can study and learn anything from here. Is the approach correct? Anything.

Here is my code (see also [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjqg23y/))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        x = $(document).scrollTop();
        y = x/5;

        if (y < 1){
            $(' .Pencil, #Middle').css('transform','none');
        }
        else{
            if (($(document).height()) > 950){}
            else{
                $('#Middle').css({
                    'transform' : 'scaleY('+ y/4 + ')',
                });
                var new_height = $('#expandablePencil')[0].getBBox().height;
                if ($('.Pencil').height() < 200){
                }
                else{
                    $('.Pencil').css({
                        'height' : x + "px"
                    });
                }
                
            }
            
        var new_height = $('#expandablePencil')[0].getBBox().height;
        }

        console.log(new_height); 
    });    
    
})
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.main{
    height: 800px;
    padding: 20px;
    
}


.svgPencil{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 30px;
    
}

.Pencil{
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    transform-origin: top;
}

#expandablePencil{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#Middle{
    transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="svgPencil">
            <div class="svgImage">
                <svg class="Pencil">
                    <use href="#pencilImage" id="expandablePencil"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                This is half part
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                This is the another half
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        



    <svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <symbol id="pencilImage" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 30 134.4" 
        style="enable-background:new 0 0 30 134.4;" xml:space="preserve">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0{fill:#4D4D4F;}
                .st1{fill:#CA4062;}
            </style>
            <g id="Top">
                <rect y="0" class="st0" width="30" height="30"/>
            </g>
            <g id="Middle">
                <rect y="42" class="st1" width="30" height="40.9"/>
            </g>
            <g id="Bottom">
                <polygon class="st0" points="15.4,134.4 23.6,116.5 6.3,116.5  "/>
                <path class="st1" d="M0,82.9v17.7C0,96.4,3.4,93,7.5,93c3.2,0,5.8,2,7,4.7c0.2,0.5,0.8,0.5,1.1,0c1.1-2.8,3.8-4.7,7-4.7
                    c4.1,0,7.5,3.4,7.5,7.5l0,0V82.9H0z"/>
            </g>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I got confused between what's working and what's not  ! (from it's id) you mean using it's id ? Do you expect the pen to stretch following scrolling event where only the middle part is stretching... ? How about a simple visual or adding a clear explanation? :)

Comment: @Bilel I have included the image and made the description even clear. Hope you can understand it better now.

Comment: In svg elements don't "push" each others, they're all independent, following only the transformations of their parents, but don't care about their siblings. So no, stretching your central element won't push the ones surrounding it, nor even extend the viewport of your full <svg>. You need to make these change all explicitely. Might be easier to use HTML for this.